# Locus such that power of a point with respect to one circle equals power with respect to another circle

Tags: circles, power-of-the-point

Lets say we have two circles call them $O_{1}$ and $O_{2}$. Let $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ be the arcs of the circles. Then when it comes to two circles, three cases arise. They intersect at two points, they intersect at one point, or they intersect at no points. Let $\omega_{a_{1}}(P)$ denote the power of a point $P$ from circle $O_{1}$. Let $\omega_{a_{2}}(P)$ denote the power of a point $P$ from circle $O_{2}$. If we define $\{P | \omega_{a_{1}}(P) = \omega_{a_{2}}(P)\}$ then what would this be equal to for all three cases?

My thoughts : If the circles intersect at two points then $P$ would just be on the line connecting the two points right? That would be where they are equal at? If that were true, how would I write that? i.e. $\{P | \omega_{a_{1}}(P) = \omega_{a_{2}}(P)\} =$?

For the case when the circles intersect at one point, $P$ is just on the tangent line both of these circles share? Again how would I write this?

The last case I am a little unsure. Maybe one can draw a line between the circles s.t. the distance from the center of each circle to the line is the same and then $P$ would be on that line?

Comment: How does the area of the circle affect the power of the point? From the books I've read, the power of a point is the product of the lengths of the pieces of any chord through that point. Are you dividing this by the area of the circle?

Comment: Im not sure what your asking. I never brought up area at all in this problem.

Comment: Ugh! I saw *arcs* on a small screen and read *area*... Sorry. However, how does the arc $a_1$ enter into the computation of $w_{a_1}(P)$?

Comment: Because if a line is tangent on the arc of the circle, its defined to be the square of that. Right? In terms of the power of a point that is.

Comment: If a line containing $P$ is tangent to the circle at $T$ then the power of $P$ relative to the circle is $|P-T|^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The [power of a point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) $p$ relative to a given circle is
$$
|p-c|^2-r^2\tag{1}
$$
where $c$ is the center of the circle and $r$ its radius. Thus, given two circles $(c_1,r_1)$ and $(c_2,r_2)$ the power of $p$ relative to both circles is equal when
$$
\begin{align}
|p|^2-2p\cdot c_1+|c_1|^2-r_1^2&=|p|^2-2p\cdot c_2+|c_2|^2-r_2^2\\
2p\cdot(c_2-c_1)&=|c_2|^2-|c_1|^2+r_1^2-r_2^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The locus of $p$ is a line perpendicular to $c_2-c_1$; that is, the line between the centers. Since the power of points on each circle is $0$, the line must pass through the points of intersection (or tangency).

For circles that do not intersect, the locus passes through the mid points of the common tangents:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Comment: It's simply glorious.

Comment: It seems this result is known as the "[chordal theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChordalTheorem.html)"